# TripleDES Java Encryprion to Javascript Decryption

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption, tripledes

I am using Java to encrypt a text payload with Triple DES. First I create an ephemeral key that I will use for encrypting the payload:

```
private byte[] createEphemeralKey() throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
    keygen.init(168);
    return keygen.generateKey().getEncoded();
}
```

Then I encrypt my payload with said key:

```
private String encryptTripleDES(byte[] ephemeralKey, String payload) throws Exception {

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(ephemeralKey, "DESede"));

    byte[] plainTextBytes = payload.getBytes();
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
}
```

Also need a padding function to ensure the data length is divisable by 8:

```
private String adjustPadding(String input, int blockSize) {

    int len = input.length() % blockSize;
    int paddingLength = (len == 0) ? 0 : (blockSize - len);

    while (paddingLength > 0) {
        input += "F";
        paddingLength--;
    }

    return input;
}
```

And here is my process end to end:

```
String data = "Marnus"
byte[] = ephemeralKey = createEphemeralKey();

String adjustedData = adjustPadding (data,8);

String encryptedPayload = encryptTripleDES(ephemeralKey, adjustedData);

String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ephemeralKey)
```

So I take the 2 variables `encryptedPayload` and `encodedKey`, that are both Base64 encoded string, and send it off via HTTP to node express app.

In the Javascript side of things, I use [node-forge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge#cipher) - Here is the part of my express app that does the decryption:

```
let nodeBuffer = Buffer.from(data, 'base64')    
let input = forge.util.createBuffer(nodeBuffer.toString('binary'))

// 3DES key and IV sizes
let keySize = 24;
let ivSize = 8;

let derivedBytes = forge.pbe.opensslDeriveBytes(ephemeralKey, null, keySize + ivSize);
let buffer = forge.util.createBuffer(derivedBytes);
let key = buffer.getBytes(keySize)
let iv = buffer.getBytes(ivSize)

let decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher('3DES-ECB', key)
decipher.start({iv: iv})
decipher.update(input)
console.log('decipher result', decipher.finish())

let decryptedResult = decipher.output.data;
```

Here is an Triples DES example in the node-forge docs:
[image]

**A few notes:**
I create a node-forge buffer from a regular buffer since I don't have a input file like the examples gives. Here is how the docs states one should create one buffer from the other:
[image]

*I use base64 as that is what I used in the java side to encode the data that was sent.

Then, I dont have a salt so I left the 2'nd param `null` in `opensslDeriveBytes` as specified in the docs I should do.

Thirdly, I am also not sure if my keysize of 24 is correct?

**My results**

So doing an end to end test yields the following:

In my Java app, the test data was `"Marnus"`, the `encryptedPayload` was `ez+RweSAd+4=` and the `encodedKey` was `vCD9mBnWHPEBiQ0BGv7gc6GUCOoBgLCu`.

Then in my javascript code `data` was obviously `ez+RweSAd+4=`(encryptedPayload) and the `ephemeralKey` was `vCD9mBnWHPEBiQ0BGv7gc6GUCOoBgLCu`(encodedKey).

After the decryption ran, the value of `decryptedResult` was `©ýÕ?µ{'`, which is obviously just garbage since it was not encoded yet, but I cant figure out which encoding to use?

I tried using `forge.util.encode64(decipher.output.data)`, but that just gave me `qf3VP7UYeyc=`, which is not right.

For what it's worth, [here is the type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEzHD.jpg) that `decipher.output`

Comment: Just a quick reply: on Java-side there is no DeriveBytes function in place - there is just a byte array directly taken from then generateKey-function. The typical DES-key is 8 bytes long so Triple DES is 3 * 8 = 24 bytes length.

Comment: The java code doesn't compile because of some bugs. Moreover, your test data doesn't seem to be consistent: You aren't using any padding (`NoPadding`). Then the length of the plaintext should be an integer multiple of the block size (8 bytes for 3DES). But the plaintext `Marnus` is only 6 bytes long. This causes a runtime error. Also, no charset is defined upon encoding (`getBytes(???)`). Please fix these problems for a defined starting point. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the post, my bad, forgot the padding function. Also, posted and answer as a solution to my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

With a lot more tweaking and testing different options, I got it working - and the good news is I managed to get it all working with the built in `crypto` library in nodejs (v12.18.4).

First things first, the JAVA side just needs a change to the key size (from 168 to 112), the rest remains the same - see below example as one single method (should be split up in final implementation of course for testability and usability):

```
//Some data:
String payload = "{\"data\":\"somedata\"}";

// Create Key
KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
keygen.init(112);
byte[] ephemeralKey = keygen.generateKey().getEncoded();

// Adjust the data, see adjustPadding method in the question for details.
String data = adjustPadding (payload,8);
// Wil now be "{"data":"somedata"}FFFFF", can just chop off extra in JS if need be. When sending JSON one knows the end of the object will always be "}"

// Do Encrypt
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(ephemeralKey, "DESede"));

byte[] plainTextBytes = data.getBytes();
byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
String encryptedPayload = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);

//Lastly, Base64 the key so you can transport it too
String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ephemeralKey)
```

on the Javascript side of things we keep it simple:

```
// I'm using TS, so change the import if you do plain JS
import crypto = require('crypto')

//need bytes from the base64 payload
let buff = Buffer.from(ephemeralKey, 'base64')

const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('des-ede3', buff, null)
decipher.setAutoPadding(false)
let decrypted = decipher.update(data, 'base64', 'utf8')
decrypted += decipher.final('utf8')

console.log(decrypted)
//{"data":"somedata"}FFFFF"
```